# Mixing multiple streams into one, posible?

Tags: streaming, broadcasting, multi-camera

How you can I implement a virtual mixer from different streams. When a streamer downloads an obs, it broadcasts the stream directly to the streaming site. Is it possible to make the stream go to another computer, where there will already be a mixing of several streams. I want to do something like 3 people turn on obs or similar software and stream to my computer, where, for example, I mix them in Vmix and send the final image to the streaming service. Is that possible?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need is to deploy an [nginx-rtmp](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module) or [nimble streamer](https://wmspanel.com/nimble) server to receive and process the signal from the obs. They can be deployed locally on your computer.([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n-EdUHNK9UI))

Second in vmix :) read this faq https://www.vmix.com/help24/index.htm?Stream.html
and install [VLC_VMIX_MODULE](http://www.vmix.com/vlcdownload)

AND Just srteam.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a mixer, like the Black Magic ATEM. This type of gear is expensive though and usually only used by TV-studios and professional broadcasting services, so I would think twice before buying one.

An alternative is hard to come by, since you need HMDI or (preferably) SDI inputs that get mixed, which you cannot simply do on a PC or Mac.

Comment: I mean not a hardware solution, but a software

Comment: The only possible software-solution I can think of is distributing the video and audio to a server. OBS can then grab the data from the URL. However, such services will cost money aswell and you probably won't get around compressing the data, which results in worse quality compared to mixing the signals on an analog mixer.